# Android Eclipse - Buttons only open one after the other

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I'm having a rather strange issue that I just can't solve.

I'm teaching myself Android Eclipse and I've created a very simple looking app with three buttons, 1)Facebook  2)LinkedIn and 3)Favourite Band. However, when I open the app on my phone, I can only press the buttons in order 1) --> 2) --> 3). For example, I can't open 2) unless i've already opened 1) and I can't open 3) unless I've already opened 2) etc. How can I change it so that I can open 3) first for example?

I've posted my java script below, any ideas would be great!

---

```
package tabletop.app4asli;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer thesong;
    Button main;
    Button main2;
    Button main3;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_go);
    main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "https://www.facebook.com/asli.akidil?fref=ts";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);

            main2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            main2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String url = "https://www.linkedin.com/pub/asli-akidil/8a/719/55a.";
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);

                    main3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
                    main3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String url = "http://www.biffyclyro.com";
                            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                            startActivity(i);

                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the code for the layout of button 2 is included in the onClick event of your button 1, and the layout of button 3 is included in the onClicked event of your button 2.

The code of onCreated() function should be looked like follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_go);
    main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                String url = "https://www.facebook.com/asli.akidil?fref=ts";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
    });
    main2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    main2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 String url = "https://www.linkedin.com/pub/asliakidil/8a/719/55a.";
                 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                 i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                 startActivity(i);
            }
    });

    main3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    main3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  String url = "http://www.biffyclyro.com";
                  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                  i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                  startActivity(i);
              }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting ClickListener for button 3 in the ClickListener of button 2 and ClickListener for button 2 in the ClickListener of button 1. So, button 2 and 3 won't initialize until button 1 and 2 are clicked respectively. You can set `OnClickListener` to all `Buttons` in a `for` loop like this:

```
    ArrayList<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>();
    buttonList.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1));
    buttonList.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.button2));
    buttonList.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.button3));

    ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
    urlList.add("https://www.facebook.com/asli.akidil?fref=ts");
    urlList.add("https://www.linkedin.com/pub/asli-akidil/8a/719/55a.");
    urlList.add("http://www.biffyclyro.com");

    for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.size(); i++) {
      final int index = i;
      final Button button = buttonList.get(index);
      final String url = urlList.get(index);
      button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
          startActivity(i);
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks IndexOutOfBounds, you taught me a new way to do buttons and it works! Great work!